# is looping possible if split horizon with poisoned reverse is used

Tags: networking, routes, network-programming

In RIP, simple split horizon scheme omits routes learned from one neighbor in updates sent to that neighbor. Split horizon with poisoned reverse includes such routes in updates, but sets their metrics to infinity

Split horizon with poisoned reverse will prevent any routing loops that involve only two routers.

However, it is still possible to end  up with patterns in which three routers are engaged in mutual deception.

Can somebody show the looping case when three routers are engaged in mutual deception while using split horizon with poisoned reverse

Answer (score 1):

More than two routers involved in mutual deception

```
A-----B
|--C--|
```

A may believe it has a route through B, B through C, and C through A
•In this case, split horizon with poison reverse was respected but it  does not help